# Struggling with simple Groovy List operations

Tags: list, collections, groovy

I've abstracted a very simple situation here, in which I want to pass a list of strings into my `cleanLines` function and get a list of strings back out. Unfortunately, I'm new to Groovy and I've spent about a day trying to get this to work with no avail. Here's a stand-alone test that exhibits the problem I'm having:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

class ConfigFileTest {

    private def tab = '\t'
    private def returnCarriage = '\r'
    private def equals = '='

    List <String> cleanLines(List <String> lines) {
        lines = lines.collect(){it.findAll(){c -> c != tab && c != returnCarriage}}
        lines = lines.findAll(){it.contains(equals)}
        lines = lines.collect{it.trim()}
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List <String> dirtyLines = ["   Colour=Red",
                                    "Shape=Square   "]

        List <String> cleanedLines = ["Colour=Red",
                                    "Shape=Square"]

        assert cleanLines(dirtyLines) == cleanedLine
    }

}
```

I believe that I've followed the correct usage for `collect()`, `findAll()` and `trim()`. But when I run the test, it crashes on the `trim()` line stating

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.util.ArrayList.trim() is applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: []

. Something's suspicious.

I've been staring at this for too long and noticed that my IDE thinks the type of my first `lines` within the `cleanLines` function is `List<String>`, but that by the second line it has type `Collection` and by the third it expects type `List<Object<E>>`. I think that String is an Object and so this might be okay, but it certainly hints at a misunderstanding on my part. What am I doing wrong? How can I get my test to pass here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a corrected script:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def tab = '\t'
@Field
def returnCarriage = '\r'
@Field
def equals = '='

List <String> cleanLines(List <String> lines) {
    lines = lines.findAll { it.contains(equals) }
    lines = lines.collect { it.replaceAll('\\s+', '') }
    lines = lines.collect { it.trim() }
}

def dirtyLines = ["   Colour=Red",
                                    "Shape=Square   "]
def cleanedLines = ["Colour=Red", "Shape=Square"]

assert cleanLines(dirtyLines) == cleanedLines
```

In general `findAll` and `collect` are maybe not mutually exclusive but have different purposes. Use `findAll` to find elements that matches certain criteria, whereas `collect` when you need to process/transform the whole list.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. However, the purpose of my first line in `cleanLines` wasn't clear. I'd like to keep all of the strings in my array, but strip out any tabs or carriage returns that appear within those strings. I think I really do want to `collect` transformed elements here. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Goldstein I have updated my answer to match your intent with the `cleanLines` function. Let me know if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Goldstein, yes, in such case you need `collect`. Will correct my answer in a moment. It's also good idea to switch the order, first look for `=` and then use regex - not in this case but in general it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
lines = lines.collect(){it.findAll(){c -> c != tab && c != returnCarriage}}`
```

replaces the original list of Strings with the list of lists. Hence NSME for ArrayList.trim(). You might want to replace `findAll{}` with `find{}`

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the first line of `cleanLines()` into two separate lines and print lines after each, you will see the problem.

```
it.findAll { c -> c != tab && c != returnCarriage }
```

will return a list of strings that match the criteria. The `collect` method is called on every string in the list of `lines`. So you end up with a list of lists of strings. I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
def cleanLines(lines) {
    return lines.findAll { it.contains(equals) }
                .collect { it.replaceAll(/\s+/, '') }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *clean* the lines like this:

```
def dirtyLines = ["   Colour=Red", "Shape=Square   "]
def cleanedLines = ["Colour=Red", "Shape=Square"]

assert dirtyLines.collect { it.trim() } == cleanedLines
```